# How to instantiate and destroy classes in python effectively and efficiently

Tags: python, class, instantiation, destroy

My classes have become complicated, and I think the way I am instantiating and not closing may be a problem... sometimes the program just hangs, code that took .2 seconds to run will take 15 seconds. It happens randomly and rebooting seems to fix it. Restarting the program without rebooting does not, I'm using cntrl+C to stop the program running on CENTOS 7.

Here's my class layout:

```
def do_stuff(self):
     pool_class = pools()
     sql_pool_insert = pool_class.generate_sql()
     print "pools done"
     sql_HD_insert = hard_drives(pool_class).generate_sql()
     print "hds done"

class pools
     class devs

class hard_drives(object):
    def __init__(self, **pool_class = pools()**):
        self.drives_table=[]
        self.assigned_drive_names =[]
        self.unassigned_drives_table=[]
        #for each pool, generate drives list actively combining
        for pool in pool_class.pool_name:
            self.drives_table = self.drives_table + pool_class.Vdevs(pool).get_drive_table()

        i=0
```

Outside of that file, I have my main program that imports the above as one of many packages. The main file calls the functions in the above file that are above the classes (because they use the classes) and sometimes the main program uses discrete functions inside classes. The problem is the pools and devs class init sections are HUGE! It takes .7 seconds to run all that code in some cases, so I want to instantiate it correctly and close it effectively. Here is a sample from the main program:

```
if (new_pool==1):
            result = mypackage.pools().create_pool(pool_to_create)
```

I really feel Like I'm doing two or three things wrong. I think, perhaps, I should just create an instance of the pools class in my main program while loop, at the top, then use that everywhere in the loop... then I would close it at the end of the loop; the loop runs every .25 seconds. I want the pool class to be initiated at the beginning of the while loop and closed at the end. Is this a good approach? This question applies equally to the Mysql InnoDB cursors I'm using, which may be another factor of the issue, how should these be handled as not to let instances of cursors and classes get out of hand? Heck, maybe I should be instantiating the entire package instead of one class in the package; i.e.:

```
with package as MyPackage:
     package.pool()...#do whatever, all inits in the package have run once and you don't have to worry about them running again so long as you use the package object for everything???
```

Maybe I'm just confused... it comes down to this... how do I control when a class init function is run... it really only needs to run at the beginning of the loop, so that the loop has fresh data to work with, and then get used everywhere else... but you see how the pools class is used by the hard_drives class... how would I handle that?